# Help with speeding up dictionary sort loop in Python?

Tags: python, performance, sorting, dictionary, python-3.x

I have a really ugly loop in my code which is really slowing down my program. The loop basically performs a dictionary comparison where, if a specific key in `dict_A` is the same as in `dict_B`, then for all matches a sort is performed which is written to a file.

```
for k, v in A_dict.items():
    for i, value in B_dict.items():
        if k == value[0]:
            sorted_B = [list(value) for key, value in groupby(sorted(B_dict.values()), key=itemgetter(1,2))]
            outfile.write('{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}\n'.format (i, k, v, value[1], value[2], value[3])
```

Unfortunately, the dictionaries both contain over a million items. Other than putting this data into a database then sorting, does anyone have any suggestions on how to speed up this loop? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your code compares a key and a value, but your text describes comparing only values. So what is a "match"? Values are the same? Also, when you use the `items()` method a whole new list is created. You can just fetch directly from B_dict using the key from A_dict.

Comment: @Keith Thanks for the catch. Hopefully my question is clear now - I am matching a key from one dictionary (dict_A) to a value from another dictionary (dict_B)

Comment: So, what do you want to write to the file when you have a match?

Comment: When I match `k == value[0]` I am writing to file some of the other values from the dictionary item that matched.

Comment: Ok.. so why are you doing the `groupby` / sort / list comprehension at all?

Comment: You're not sorting the data that you're writing, your sorting the whole dictionary (not in place -- a copy of the dictionary's data) and saving it into a list, that you're not doing anything with.

Comment: Anyway, either explain the purpose of the sort, or try the loop given in my answer -- it should be much faster. It looks like you just need to check if `value[0]` is a key in `A_dict`, which is very fast -- I'm not overwriting `k`, since `k` isn't used in my version of the loop.

Comment: The purpose of the sort is that I need the data sorted in the output file for another application. Would it be better to use your code and then sort after writing to file?

Comment: You're saying you want the lines in the ouput file sorted? You're not doing that now. Either sort `B` before the loop, or instead of writing in the loop, save the lines in a list, sort them after the loop, then write them.

Comment: This would be much clearer with a sample of input and the expected output.

Comment: I think if we had a better picture of your overall goal and dataset we could come up with something faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example code may be inaccurate, but as written,

```
sorted_B = [list(value) for key, value in 
                groupby(sorted(B_dict.values()), key=itemgetter(2,3))]
```

will be the same every time... why is it in a loop at all?

Also

```
for k, v in A_dict.items():
    for i, value in B_dict.items():
        if k == value[0]:
            outfile.write('{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}\n'.format(
                i, k, v, value[1], value[2], value[3])
```

Looks like it could just be written as

```
for i, value in B_dict.items():
    k = value[0]
    if k in A_dict:
        outfile.write('{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}\n'.format(
            i, k, A_dict[k], value[1], value[2], value[3])
```

Which should be faster -- it's linear time rather than quadratic time.

Comment: as always, thank you for the help. i was attempted to put sorted_B in the loop so that only the items where `if k == value[0]:` would need to be sorted.

Comment: You're sorting the whole dictionary though, not just the items that match. Is what you want to get a list of all the matching items then sort that?

Comment: I not sure I understand how you have rewritten the dictionary matching loop - in particular, `k = value[0]`.`k` is the key to the dictionary.  Won't this rebind k to value[0] from the other dictionary. Sorry if I am being unclear.

Comment: You need to better explain what you want to write to the file.

Comment: For each item in dict_B there will be always be a match from dict_A, so I will need to go through the entire dictionary I think. However, the reverse is not necessarily true - there are items in dict_A that may not be matched in dict_B.

Comment: You don't need to iterate over `A`, just over `B`. Iterating `B` for every item in `A` then comparing is `O(len(A)*len(B))` while iterating over just `B` and checking for each item in `A` is `O(len(B))` because dictionary lookups are constant time.

Comment: Ok, I now understand! I can't think you enough agf. Your solution speed up my code dramatically. I do this sort of thing quite a bit so your explanations were really helpful. I ultimately converted the dictionary to a list, then sorted, then performed the match on the sorted list.